# MSE update KB2310138 causes system to hang

Tags: windows-7, ms-security-essentials

A particular system I've been looking at has been having intermittent hanging issues. The system seems to hang on start-up and is generally slow. I restored the system to a state previous to a Windows Update. One of the updates that was installed after the system restore point was MSE update KB2310138. I've tried to reinstall MSE and reinstall the update with no success. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Did the restore resolve the performance issues?

Comment: I've been experiencing system hangs too. Restoring to before this update seems to have corrected the problem so far.

Answer (score -1):

So just starting up my computer this morning took 30 minutes.  Why? Because it was configuring an update (KB2310138) upon bootup.  I thought the configuration was hung, because It got to 100% progress and then appeared to do nothing for about 15 minutes.  I was overly patient with it, and it luckily it paid off, it finally went into "cleaning up" and then took about another 15 minutes to complete that.  I thought to myself, wow what in the world could be taking so long? It is replacing my entire OS, giving me an entirely new hard drive, reinstalling every app I own, or what? Sheesh. Took freaking forever.  Then I find out its just one tiny little security patch for MS Security Essentials...What the heck?  Insane.  Anyway, just posting this so others will know not to lose patience with the install as it may appear to be hung at the 100% completion stage, but it is actually still working, it just takes a huge amount of time to get from 100% complete to the cleaning up stage, then takes a ton of time to get past that too.  Be patient with it and happy computing.